# Take screenshots of all desktop spaces on MacOS

Tags: macos, screenshot, mission-control

I need to create zsh script or c++ app to get screenshots of all active desktop spaces for current user. Is there any way to do it?
I planned to use `screencapture`, but didn't find how to choose a desktop and so it only takes a screenshot of the desktop space that is now on the screen.